# JSF обновление страницы без редиректа

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Ситуация такая, на странице есть:

- Добавить элемент;
- Таблица этих элементов;
- Навигация состоящая из этих элементов;
- всплывающие меседжы по различным событиям на странице(например успешное добавление элемента)

Если страницу отредиректить то меседжи пропадают, так как все параметры сбрасываются, а если ее не редиректить то информация не обновляется. Может можно как то сымитировать редирект(форвард не подходит, элементы не обновляются)?

ЗЫ
я использую primefaces, jsf

**UPD**

Пробую еще один вариант, храню все нужные параметры в сесии.
Как заставить сообщение высвечиваться по умолчанию ?

```
<p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
```

в бине :

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "ioi", "lol"));
```

получаем:

```
INFO: WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
sourceId=null[severity=(INFO 0), summary=(ioi), detail=(lol)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу 2 варианта:

1. Не обновлять страницу полностью, а подгружать нужный контент через AJAX (в jsf есть встроеная реализация).
2. Мессаджи хранить в сессии, а при обновлении страницы рендерить те мессаджи, которые не должны пропасть.

Comment: у primefaces есть такая штука messages, ее то я и использую и пока что еще не понимаю как ее можно хранить в сесии, так как разбираю primefaces использую относительно недавно

Comment: А как вы отправляете месседжи с сервера? Вы же делаете что-нибудь вроде    

    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Sample info message", "PrimeFaces Rocks");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("somekey", msg);

Так вот, `msg` можно засунуть в сессию и по обновлению страницы снова вызывать `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage()`

Comment: В реализации одного из бинов который рисует страницу делаю так :

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "ioi", "lol"));

получаю

    INFO: WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
    sourceId=null[severity=(INFO 0), summary=(ioi), detail=(lol)]

пробовал делать так

    <f:ajax execute="name" render="@all" />

не работает

Answer (score 0):

Если обновлять только форму?

```
<f:ajax execute="name" render="@form" />
```

render="@all" приводит именно к редиректу и спросу состояния в начальное.